# How to inductively prove a graph property?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

I'm stuck on Part 1, I can't find it inductively. The distance from $$[k, k + 1]$$ is going to be a non-zero positive value with a vertex. Therefore, there is going to be a positive edge weight from $$w(uv)$$ that goes from $$[k, k + 1].$$ Therefore, there exists a v on the set of V such at $$A[u, k + 1] = A[v, k] + w(uv).$$

**The Problem**

Given an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$ with positive edge weights $w(e)$ for each edge $e \in E$, we want
to find a dynamic programming algorithm to compute the longest path in $G$ from a given source $s$
that contains at most $n$ edges.

To do this first define $A[v, k]$ as the weight for the longest path from node $s$ to node $v$ of at most
$k$ edges.

1. First we need to prove an optimal sub-structure by induction. Show
   that if $A[v, k]$ is the weight of the longest path, then for all $u
     \in V$, there exists a $v \in V$ such that $A[u, k + 1] = A[v, k] + w(uv)$.
2. Describe a dynamic programming algorithm that finds the optimal
   length using part 1.  Specifically: describe (1) the OPT recurrence
   (2) the running time of the iterative solution for computing the OPT
   table.

Comment: Do u understand what the entries of the matrix mean?

Comment: Matrix, I believe it's a graph and not a matrix?

Comment: $A$ is a matrix, $G$ is a graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would like to know what is the maximum weight path of length at MOST $k+1$ from source $s$ to vertex $u$. Obviously such a path must exist (assuming connected).

Now, assume such a path EXIST (we know nothing more!!), and we can describe the path by the sequence of vertices it goes through, that is, path $p_1:=\{s,v_0,...,v\}$. Note that we don't actually know the sequence of vertices, just that if such a path exist then it must have a sequence of vertices that describe the path.

Now, consider the last vertex on said sequence before $v$. Call it $u$. Of course, the path (up to $u$) can have a length of AT MOST $k$. Note that from the sequence, edge($u$,$v$) is in the maximum weight path to $v$ (that has length at most $k+1$).

I'm going to show why the weight of the path $p_1$ minus the edge($u$,$v$) is also the entry of $A[u,k]$. That is, the path $p_1$ minus the edge($u$,$v$) (let's call this $p_2$) is the maximum weight path from the source $s$ to vertex $u$ of length at most $k$.

Suppose $p_2$ is not the maximum weight path from $s$ to $u$. That is, there exist path $p_3$ that has a larger weight, and it has at most $k$ edges. But then $p_3$ added with edge($u$,$v$) has larger weight than $p_1$ (our maximum weight path from $s$ to $v$ with length at most k+1). Thus we have a contradiction.

To recap: we have proved that the weight of the path $p_2$ must be the entry of $A[u,k]$. But what is the weight of path $p_2$? Remember that we get $p_2$ by deleting edge($u$,$v$) from path $p_1$. Of course, it means that the weight of $p_2$ is weight of $p_1$ minus the weight of edge($u$,$v$).

$$
A[v,k+1] - w(uv) = A[u,k], \implies A[v,k+1]  = A[u,k] + w(uv)
$$

Comment: Feel free to ask further questions

Comment: Well but we have to be careful here though. What if $p_3$ contains the vertex $v$?

Your argument carries through if we replace 'path', where repeating vertices are not allowed, with 'walk', where repeating vertices are allowed.

Comment: Meanwhile, unless P=NP, there is no algorithm to find the longest path with at most $k$ edges in a weighted graph starting from a vertex $s$; if so, then there would be an algorithm that would find a Hamiltonian path starting from a vertex $s$. Indeed, ask for the longest path starting from $s$ that has at most $|V(G)|$ vertices, where the weight of each edge in $G$ is exactly $1$.

Comment: @Mike I.. considered a directed simple graph. I will try to correct the answer

Comment: @Mike is the question correct? The first part is the same as asking "show that for any vertex $v$, that has a maximum weight path $p_v$ of length at most $k+1$, at least one of it's neighbours $u$ must have the same path $p_v$ minus one edge($u$,$v$) as it's maximum weight path of length at most $k$". If that re-wording is correct, I can draw a graph where that statement is not true.

Comment: Said graph: imagine a triangle $abc$. Let it's top vertex $a$ be the source. Draw a line that corresponds to the triangle's height, it will intersect the source and the base of the triangle (an edge). Add another vertex $v$ on the intersection between the height and the base. Let all edges have weight 1. Now let $k+1$ = 3.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your example, it is hard to see what is happening without a picture. Another example is let $G$ a complete bipartite graph on $n$ vertices, with (A) 2 vertices $s$ and $u$ on one side, and (B) a set $T$ of $n-2 \ge 5$ vertices on the other side. So every vertex in $T$ is adjacent to both $s$ and $u$ in $G$. But no two vertices in $T$ are adjacent to each other, and $s$ and $u$ are *not* adjacent to each other either. Then the set of vertices adjacent to $u$ in $G$ is precisely $T$. Furthermore, every path from $s$ to a vertex in $T$ of $ \ge 3$ contains $u$.

Comment: So no, 1. as in the OP's question is not true. It would be true if it were walks and not paths.